# How To logout and close any active forms in Delphi

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7, logout, active-form

Sorry for my bad English, first this is the logout syntax.

When I click logout, all active forms keep showing up and not closing.

```
procedure Tf_utama.KELUAR1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if MessageDlg('Logout ??',mtConfirmation,mbOKCancel,0)=mrOK 
then

DATAINPUTAN1.Visible:=False;
INFODATA1.Enabled:=False;
TRANSAKSI.Enabled:=False;
LAPORAN1.Enabled:=False;
PENGATURAN1.Enabled:=False;

f_databuku:=nil;
f_rakbuku:=nil;
f_permintaan_pembeli:=nil;
f_rakbuku:=nil;
f_pengguna:=nil;
f_transaksi_penjualan:=nil;
f_transaksi_pembelian:=nil;
f_supplier:=nil;

StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:='Nama Pengguna :';
StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text:='Hak Akses :';
end;
```

On each form to close I am using:

```
procedure Tf_caribuku.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
Action:=caFree;
f_caribuku:=nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you close and free the form. You are just assigning `nil` to form pointers, which doesn't close them. What you have to call is `TForm.Close()`. Also, you have to open your `if MessageDlg(...` statement with `begin..end;` blocks if you want to execute multiple commands if statement is satisfied. So your code would look something like this:

```
procedure Tf_utama.KELUAR1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MessageDlg('Logout ??',mtConfirmation,mbOKCancel,0) = mrOK then 
  begin 
    DATAINPUTAN1.Visible:=False;
    INFODATA1.Enabled:=False;
    TRANSAKSI.Enabled:=False;
    LAPORAN1.Enabled:=False;
    PENGATURAN1.Enabled:=False;

    f_databuku.Close;
    f_rakbuku.Close;
    f_permintaan_pembeli.Close;
    f_rakbuku.Close;
    f_pengguna.Close;
    f_transaksi_penjualan.Close;
    f_transaksi_pembelian.Close;
    f_supplier.Close;

    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:='Nama Pengguna :';
    StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text:='Hak Akses :';
  end;
end;
```

Also, if any of forms you're trying to close is not created, I believe it will fail with AV exception. Better way to do this is to make another class which will serve as form container, e.g. `TFormContainer`, where you can Add and Remove forms on need. That way, upon logout, opened forms will be in `TFormContainer` class, and you can close them.

Comment: still error, maybe because  not every form open or  not created. and how to use `TformContainer`? sorry i Still don't get it.

Comment: Finally i can solve this.

`procedure Tf_utama.KELUAR1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if MessageDlg('Logout ??',mtConfirmation,mbOKCancel,0) = mrOK then
  begin 
    DATAINPUTAN1.Visible:=False;
    INFODATA1.Enabled:=False;
    TRANSAKSI.Enabled:=False;
    LAPORAN1.Enabled:=False;
    PENGATURAN1.Enabled:=False;`

    f_databuku.Free;
    f_rakbuku.Free;
    f_permintaan_pembeli.Free;
    f_rakbuku.Free;
    f_pengguna.Free;
    f_transaksi_penjualan.Free;
    f_transaksi_pembelian.Free;
    f_supplier.Free;
     end;
    end;`

Comment: You should not call SomeForm.Free. Why? Doing so you prevent corect form termination. For instance if you free up the min form the application won't close as it would othevise. And that is becouse the form can't notiffy TApplication class about its destruction, also calling Someform.free prevents OnClose or OnCanClose events to be fired.

Comment: that true, and now i find syntax to resolved it. With Use `if Assigned(f_databuku) then f_databuku.Close;` like that.